# Why does a variance annotation cause this subtyping relation not to be inferred by Scala?

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, covariance

In the code

```
  sealed trait Node[+T]
  case class I[C]() extends Node[C => C]

  def test[A, B](n: Node[A => B]) = n match {
    case i: I[c] =>
      val cId: c => c = identity _
      val ab: A => B = cId
  }
```

Scala gives the error that `c => c` is not `A => B`. Removing the variance annotation in `Node[+T]` solves the error.

I am puzzled because I believe that, in the presence of the variance annotation, the match `i: I[c]` should create the rule `(c => c) <:< (A => B)`, which is all that is needed for that line to compile. What am I missing?

Comment: Function parameters are CONTRAvariant on their arguments. It is not an answer, but a guess.

Comment: @MikeG. Hm I wondered if that could be involved but I can't see how -- the variance of `=>` doesn't seem to be in play here. Of course, if I'm right about that, I should be able to reproduce this example without function types and it should still fail. Maybe I'll try that.

Comment: After some further experimentation this seems to not be related to the variance of `=>`... or even to `=>` specifically, but seems to have something to do with the repeated type variable in `c => c`. Still not sure why that matters.

Comment: That was a good one. I had no intuition whether it was a patmat bug; I went thru the motions like the comments. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8563

Comment: I think the problem is in type variance. Specifically when `i: I[C]` is matched, `c =:= A` should be true. (And thus all following statements should compiles)

Comment: I give another test where `Node[T, R]` is declared and `I[C]() extends Node[C, C]`. And in the `match..case..` , `implicitly[A =:= B]` compiles. Similarly `c =:= A`. However, when type variance was added it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer : `c` at runtime is erased and your match will not work correctly. You are matching on `I[_]`**

In case your `Node` is invariant `Node[A]` is a subclass of `Node[B]` only iff `A=B`.  This forces

`n` passed to `test[A, B](n: Node[A => B])`   to be really  `Node[A => B]`

If you reason down, if your `n` matches a pattern `I[Something]` for whatever `Something`, A and B has to of type `Something`

In case Node is covariant, because of definition of `Function1[-A,+B]` you can have a call to

`test[A,B](n)` where  `n` is `Node[A1 =>B1]` where `A1>:A` and `B1<:B` **(equation 1)**

so if your `n` matches a `I[C]` it means that `A1 = C` and `B1 = C`

If you replace `C` in the **equation 1**, you will get `C >: A` and `C<:B` **(equation 2)**

Therefore the following assignment is not valid anymore

```
f: A => B = C => C
```

For the left hand side to be assignable from the right hand side, we need `C => C` to be `Function1[-A,+B]`

This means that `A >: C` and `B <: C` but from equation 2 we know that this does not hold (except for the case C = A and C = B, and there is no evidence to be the case, unless your Node is **invariant**)